# Rails 4 - Asset Pipeline path is 'images/file.jpg' instead of 'assets/file.jpg'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I've been in a battle w/ Rails 4 to try and make it pick up my assets and create the correct links.  Generally, a combination of server restarts and hard refreshes will get the url's to come through correctly, but not always.  `tmp:clear` and `assetpipeline:clobber` aren't working for me either.

The issue in question is with the image_path method.  I'm current in a custom Form object, so I've done this:

```
class WalletForm
  include ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper

  def give_me_path
    image_path("logo.jpg")
  end
end
```

image_path is giving me "images/logo.jpg" in development and test mode.  This ought to be "assets/logo.jpg".  I've noticed in the past that when rails can't find the image, it will use images/logo.jpg, instead of assets.  I'm guessing that this is in case you've put it in your public/images folder outside of the pipeline.  But the file does exist in `app/assets/images`, and is in the right place.  (I've copied and pasted the filename, I've tried renaming the file as well.  I've restarted the web server, restarted pow)  I even precompiled the assets with `RAILS_ENV=test` to try and verified that my logo was picked up by the pipeline, assuming

I'm not sure what else to look into.  Any suggestions?