# Rails 4 ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path returning correct path in rails console but not in controller's action

Tags: asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4.2

**Ruby 2.3.0**, **Rails 4.2.6**

This is really **puzzling**. I am working on a feature in development environment and it requires me to have the full path to my `application.css` and `application.js`. Since on production the pre-compiled assets are used those files name would contain fingerprint hash. Thus to make the code work uniformly in every environment I am using in my controller action following code to print the asset paths:

```
puts ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("application.css")
puts ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("application.js")
```

Strangely the first line is printing the correct fingerprinted path to `public/assets/application*.css`, however second line just prints `/applicatio‌​n.js`.

I have manually precompiled the assets and they are available in `public/assets` folder in my Rails application.

I tried experimenting in many ways i.e. restarting server many times clearing the assets cache from `tmp` folder, repeatedly pre-compiled assets etc but the result is same for `application.css` i.e. I am getting the expected path but for `application.js` I am getting `/applicatio‌​n.js` instead of its fingerprinted path.

The strange thing is when I go to the rails console it is returning the correct paths.

> Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.6)
>   2.3.0 :001 > ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("application.css")
>    => "/assets/application-b487959d50fc3739b8f8487965cdc80e824f7769aa3930f0bd56e336fdda9f69.css" 
>   2.3.0 :002 > ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("application.js")
>    => "/assets/application-2f38868cbe464116d568678be27b17283dbbce3d65ef00347f7e54d50ceb9640.js" 
>   2.3.0 :003 >

I am totally puzzled what is going on with the same code in controller's action. Can anybody please explain why this inconsistent behavior?

I found following references on how to get the asset path in controller:

[Access Asset Path from Rails Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827078/access-asset-path-from-rails-controller)

[Rails 4 - Asset Pipeline path is 'images/file.jpg' instead of 'assets/file.jpg'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349656/rails-4-asset-pipeline-path-is-images-file-jpg-instead-of-assets-file-jpg)

[How to give fingerprint css path in production rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736713/how-to-give-fingerprint-css-path-in-production-rails-4/23819781#comment65095450_23819781)

Thanks.

**app/views/layouts/application.html.haml**

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{:content => "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}/
    %title= Settings.app_name
    = favicon_link_tag
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    ....
    ....
    ....

    = javascript_tag nil, src: "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.blockUI/2.70/jquery.blockUI.min.js"
```

Comment: Can you post your layout code?  Is it possible turbolinks is not set to true on the `application.js`   see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710277/turbolinks-and-controller-specific-assets

Comment: @lacostenycoder I have edited my post to include my layout code. As can be seen in the header it contains `'data-turbolinks-track' => true` for both `application.css` and `application.js`.